# $4$ idempotent operators $E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4$ $:V\to V$ such that $E_1+E_2+E_3+E_4=I$ but don't partition the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ such that $charF \neq 2$

Can anyone help me think of $4$ idempotent operators $E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4$ $:V\to V$ such that $E_1+E_2+E_3+E_4=I$ but $\{E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4 \}$ doesn't partition the identity on V (e.g. $E_iE_j\neq0$ when $i\neq j$)?

Comment: Constant functions (unless they are constant zero) are not linear operators.

Comment: @HenningMakholm would you mind explaining why?

Comment: @LHS: I believe the linear operator no matter where does it act, applied to zero gives zero.

Comment: A linear operator $f$ must satisfy $f(\vec 0)=f(0\cdot v)=0\cdot f(v)=\vec 0$.

Comment: What kind of vector space?

Comment: A vector space $V$ over $F$ such that $charF \neq 2$

Comment: Your edit is incorrect. The sum of those four operators is $2I$, not $I$.

Comment: @joriki: You are correct, do you have any idea how we could use $charF\neq 2$ to solve this?

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but the problem is equivalent to this one. Consider the associative $F$-algebra with $1$ generated by the symbols $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ subject to the relations $e_i^2=e_i$ and $\sum e_i=1$. Do we have $e_1e_2=0$?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: We need to find $E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4$ such that $E_iE_j\neq 0$, but that is similar

Comment: I think this is equivalent. If $e_ie_j=0$ for $i\not=j$, the example you're looking for doesn't exist. If $e_1e_2\not=0$, we can take for $E_i$ the left multiplication by $e_i$.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: Hmmm, ok, but how could we construct examples?

Comment: Just to make sure: do you agree with my previous comment?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: I think you're probably right, but you can have that as the case for 3  idempotent transformations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A partial answer: At least in characteristic 0 and finite dimension this is impossible.

The trace of an idempotent matrix equals its rank (as can be seen by choosing a basis that extends a basis for the range of the linear operator). On the other hand, the *sum* of the four traces must be $\mathop{\rm Tr}I$, which is the dimension of the entire vector space. But since $E_1+E_2+E_3+E_4=I$, this means that the ranges of the four operators must be direct summands of the entire space. Then choose a basis for each of the summands, combine them to a basis for $V$ and write down the matrices in this basis. For each row only one of the matrices is allowed to have nonzero entries, but since the sum of the matrices is given, this determines them completely, and it is seen that indeed they partition the identity.

On the other hand, there's a trivial solution in characteristic $3$: simply let $E_1=E_2=E_3=E_4=I$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, about the trivial solution, do they not have to be distinct?

Comment: You didn't ask for _distinct_ operators in your question.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess they don't have to be as a set of one element could still partition the identity

Comment: +1 for the "trivial" solution (that is not so trivial to me).

Comment: But if you want distinct solutions you could take diag(1,1,0,0,0), diag(1,0,1,0,0), diag(1,0,0,1,0), and diag(1,0,0,0,1) in $(\mathbb F_3)^5$.